# What does b"string" mean in dd() function?

Tags: php, laravel-5, character-encoding

`dd($result);`

Result:

```
...
+description: "عند...ترنت."    
+keywords: b"°ó¨Ü¨ü¨ê...Ü°®"
...
```

`+keywords` has the letter 'b' in front of the string, description does not have that... What does the 'b' mean? And if it is possible, how can I convert the string?

Btw, this is the result if I var_dump the keywords:
`string(116) "���,����,�,��,����������,����������,��,��������,�������,������:"`

I think it has to do something with charset, i'm using UTF-8.

Answer (score 11):

If you read: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html (which is what Laravel is using) you can see:

[image]

So the answer is the string is not valid in UTF-8 (I am guessing `b` stands for binary).

Maybe check if you can detect the encoding if it's something else.

Comment: thanks for helping, this anwer pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: @djl so what actually helped for you