# php setlocale adding 'b' before any variable with date

Tags: php, laravel, date, locale

This line of code: 
`$date = strftime("%B", strtotime(Date("F"))) . " " . Date("y");` is supposed to return: `"March 18"`, according to the below locale config

```
cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

What I have in my php file is: `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_PT');`, in order to return : `"Março 18"`. Previously, this was working just fine, but what is happening today is that the value `$date` is returning `b"Março 18"`.

My 'trial-by-combat' resulted in these 5 final results:

```
$str = "Hi";
$dateOne = strftime("%B", strtotime(Date("F")));
$dateTwo = Date("y");
$strAndDateOne = $str.$dateOn;
$strAndDateTwo = $str.$dateTwo;
```

Output:

```
dd($str,$dateOne,$dateTwo,$strAndDateOne,$strAndDateTwo);

"Hi"
b"Março"
"18"
b"HiMarço"
"Hi18"
```

I have no idea what that b is and my function stopped working. (I honestly can't remember if the b was there previously, but I'm positive that it wasn't).

What was different from before to now:
I created a swapfile (between yesterday and today) that is no longer in use and that was the only thing I've done on the machine.

Comment: Check this question, this has been previously answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224408/what-does-bstring-mean-in-dd-function

Comment: this has helped me, thanks @namelivia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this topic is old, but in order to fix this issue you will need to put your "strftime" method inside the "utf8_encode" method:

```
utf8_encode(strftime("%B", strtotime(Date("F"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_PT.UTF-8');

You need to specify "UTF-8"